# monitoring hadoop cluster with ganglia

Tags: hadoop, metrics, slave, ganglia

I'm new to hadoop and trying to monitor the working of a multi node cluster using ganglia, The setup of gmond is done on all nodes and ganglia monitor only on the master.However,there are hadoop metrics graphs only for the master node and just system metrics for slaves. Do these hadoop metrics on the master include the slave metrics as well?Or is there any mistake in configuration files? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read [this](http://hakunamapdata.com/ganglia-configuration-for-a-small-hadoop-cluster-and-some-troubleshooting/) in order to understand how metrics flow between master and slave.

However, I would like to brief that, in genral, hadoop based or hbase based metrics are directly emitted/ sent to the master server (By master server, I mean the server on which gmetad is installed). All other OS related metrics are first collected by gmond installed on the corresponding slave and then redirected to the gmond installed on the master server.

So, if you are not getting any OS related metrics of slave servers then there is some misconfiguration in your gmond.conf. To know more about how to configure ganglia, please read [this](http://sachinsharm.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/setup-and-configure-ganglia-3-6-on-centosrhel-6-3/). This has helped me and could help you for sure, if you go through carefully.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your configuration files.

More precisely, in transmitting / collecting the data, whichever approach you use.